# MYSQL stored procedure cursor returning null value

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a Session table in Mysql. I am trying to fetch the result from this table using mysql stored procedure cursor but everytime it's returning null. Here is the code what I am trying to fetch resultset.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getSession`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE site_id INTEGER(20);
    DECLARE sess CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT siteid FROM Sessions WHERE cstate=1;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN sess;
    get_session: LOOP        
        FETCH sess INTO site_id;
        IF done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE get_session;
        END IF;         
        SELECT site_id;
    END LOOP get_session;

   CLOSE sess;
END
```

Comment: `LEAVE get_replay` should be `LEAVE get_session`

Comment: Sorry it's typo mistake. BTW I resolved it.

Comment: A typo like that should not be possible, unless you are also editing out portions of your code before showing it to us, in which case, you might not be giving us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I don't see a problem with this procedure, assuming `SELECT siteid FROM Sessions WHERE cstate=1 AND siteid IS NULL;` does not find any rows.  If it does find rows, that would be your explanation.

Comment: What is the error message? What is returning null?